# Why DllImport for C bool as UnmanagedType.I1 throws but as byte it works

Tags: c#, c, boolean, pinvoke, visual-studio-2013

### Here is a simple C code (VS 2013 C++ project, "compiled as C"):

```
typedef struct {
    bool bool_value;
} BoolContainer;

BoolContainer create_bool_container (bool bool_value)
{
    return (BoolContainer) { bool_value };
}
```

### Here is my P/Invoke wrapper

```
public partial class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport(LibraryName, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern BoolContainer create_bool_container([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)] bool bool_value);
}
```

### Here are the managed versions of the `BoolContainer`:

First is throwing `MarshalDirectiveException: Method's type signature is not PInvoke compatible.`:

```
public struct BoolContainer // Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(BoolContainer)) = 1
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)] // same with UnmanagedType.U1
    public bool bool_value;
}
```

Second is working:

```
public struct BoolContainer // Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(BoolContainer)) = 1
{
    public byte bool_value;
}
```

Test code:

```
BoolContainer boolContainer = NativeMethods.create_bool_container(true);
```

Is seems like `DllImport` ignores `MarshalAs` for any boolean members in the returned structure. Is there a way to keep `bool` in the managed declaration?

Comment: Returning structs as function return values is risky at best. Different compilers have different ways to do this. It seems that you cannot marshal `bool` in a struct at all as a function return value. If p/invoke was actually documented then we'd be able to work out why. I suspect an `out` parameter to the function is the way forward.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Structs as return types are pretty difficult in interop, they don't fit a CPU register.  This is handled in native code by the caller reserving space on its stack frame for the return value and passing a pointer to the callee.   Which then copies the return value through the pointer.  In general a pretty troublesome feature, different C compilers have different strategies to pass that pointer.  The pinvoke marshaller assumes MSVC behavior.

This is a problem with structs that are not *blittable*, in other words when its layout is no longer an exact match with the unmanaged struct that the native code needs.  That requires an extra step to convert the unmanaged struct to the managed struct, the equivalent of Marshal.PtrToStructure().  You see this for example if you add a string field to your struct.  That makes it non-blittable since the C string has to be converted to a System.String, you'll get the exact same exception.

A similar kind of problem in your case, *bool* is also a very difficult type to interop with.  Caused by the C language not having the type and it getting added later with highly incompatible choices.  It is 1 byte in C++ and the CLR, 2 bytes in COM, 4 bytes in C and the winapi.  The pinvoke marshaller picked the winapi version as the default, making it match BOOL, the most common reason to pinvoke.  This forced you to add the [MarshalAs] attribute and that also requires extra work, again to be done by the equivalent of Marshal.PtrToStructure().

So what the pinvoke marshaller is missing is the support for this *extra* step, custom marshaling of the return value after the call.  Not sure if this was a design constraint or a resource constraint.  Probably both, ownership of non-blittable struct members is completely unspecified in unmanaged languages and guessing at it, *especially* as a return value, very rarely turns out well.  So they may well have made the call that working on the feature just wasn't worth the low odds of success.  This is a guess of course.

Using *byte* instead is a fine workaround.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me at this answer!  So is the only scenario where `MarshalAs` can be used the case where you are passing things *into* unmanaged functions by value (passing by pointer in an unsafe context also has the same problem)?

Comment: Creating a *managed* pointer also requires a blittable struct.  Very rarely a practical problem when you pass a struct as an argument, you trivially generate an unmanaged pointer with the *ref* keyword on the argument.