# What is wrong with my DLLImport(s) in my C# project for my custom C++ DLL?

Tags: c#, c++, dll, pinvoke

I am currently learning C++ (for eventually creating DLL's for Hooks).  I have strengths in C# and would like to access the DLL's via pInvoke/DllImports.

I am using VS 2019 (and .NET Framework 4.7.2).  As a sample for learning purposes, I have replicated the DLL as well as the C++ (console app) as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp?view=vs-2019.  This is working perfectly fine (as expected).

Now when I start trying to import the DLL into a C# Project I am running into problems (which I believe are DllImport related)

In the sample (c++) console app (which is working):

```cpp
int main()
{
    // Initialize a Fibonacci relation sequence.
    fibonacci_init(1, 1);
    // Write out the sequence values until overflow.
    do {
        std::cout << fibonacci_index() << ": " << fibonacci_current() << std::endl;
    } while (fibonacci_next());
    // Report count of values written before overflow.
    std::cout << fibonacci_index() + 1 << " Fibonacci sequence values fit in an " << "unsigned 64-bit integer." << std::endl;
}
```

In the C# test console app (not working properly):

```cs
    class Program
    {

        [DllImport("MathLibrary.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        internal static extern void fibonacci_init(ulong a, ulong b);

        [DllImport("MathLibrary.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl))]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool fibonacci_next();

        [DllImport("MathLibrary.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        internal static extern ulong fibonacci_current();

        [DllImport("MathLibrary.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        internal static extern uint fibonacci_index();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            // Initialize a Fibonacci relation sequence.
            fibonacci_init(1, 1);
            // Write out the sequence values until overflow.
            do {
                Console.WriteLine($"{fibonacci_index()}: {fibonacci_current()}");
            } while (fibonacci_next());
            // Report count of values written before overflow.
            Console.WriteLine($"{fibonacci_index() + 1} Fibonacci sequence values fit in an unsigned 64-bit integer.");
        }
    }
```

In the working (C++) app, the loop reaches 92 and prints
`92: 12200160415121876738` and then exits the loop and prints `93 Fibonacci sequence values fit in an unsigned 64-bit integer.`

However, in the failing (C#) app, it works up until the `92: 12200160415121876738`, but rather than exiting the loop, `fabonacci_next()` continues to return `true` and it keeps looping the line `92: 12200160415121876738` (no more increments, and never exits).

For the DllImport in C# I have tried both:

```cs
[DllImport("MathLibrary.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl))]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool fibonacci_next();
```

and:

```cs
[DllImport("MathLibrary.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl))]
public static extern bool fibonacci_next();
```

Same results either way. If someone could explain to me what I am doing wrong with the DllImport (causing it not to ever return true, when the same DLL works properly when linked to a C++ console app).

--- UPDATE ---

So the solution to the example above changing `[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]` to `[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]` does work (with further important related information provided in the links given by GSerg in the comments below).

--- UPDATE 2 ---

(@David) I did intentionally (and incorrectly) leave out the exports as they were in the link I provided to the original DLL 'walkthrough' (my apologies).  For completeness of the question the exports are:

```cpp
#ifdef MATHLIBRARY_EXPORTS
#define MATHLIBRARY_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define MATHLIBRARY_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

extern "C" MATHLIBRARY_API void fibonacci_init(unsigned long long a, unsigned long long b);
extern "C" MATHLIBRARY_API bool fibonacci_next();
extern "C" MATHLIBRARY_API unsigned long long fibonacci_current();
extern "C" MATHLIBRARY_API unsigned fibonacci_index();
```

Comment: Please explain the downvote, maybe I can rephrase something?

Comment: C++'s `bool` is not C#'s `bool`. `UnmanagedType.Bool` is C++'s `BOOL`, not `bool`. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/32110152/11683.

Comment: @GSerg I see, I actually only added that as I have seen it used when working with other p/Invoke stuff, originally I didn't have that, but as it wasn't working thought that might have been the issue.

Comment: Not having that is also a problem (see https://stackoverflow.com/q/53898839/11683).

Comment: ok, bingo, so `UnmanagedType.I1` seems to do the trick!  Other conversions in the example seem correct (C++ `unsigned long long` equals C# `ulong`), but my cheat sheet said C++ BOOL equals C# bool, so I assumed that C++ BOOL was the same as C++ bool.

Comment: Both those SO questions are helpful with this learning process as well thank!

Comment: Without knowledge of the C++ function declarations this question is incomplete

Comment: If you're happy with what you found, you should answer yourself so it closes the question

Comment: @SimonMourier they changed things, I thought I had to wait 24 hours before I could answer my own question.  (plus I was hoping that someone else with better 'terminology' skills would answer first :)

Comment: For future reference we prefer to make questions self contained here if possible. Leaving the detail in offsite links makes it harder for us to absorb that detail and opens the way for link rot.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Agreed, I understand and hence my update and apology noting I incorrectly excluded it after your previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

tldr;

The solution was to simply change the DllImport for the fibonacci_next() import to:

```cs
[DllImport("MathLibrary.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl))]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]
public static extern bool fibonacci_next();
```

---

A little extra:

Technically that was all that was necessary to answer this question.  For those who found this question under similar terms, I am adding a bit more info below, as the real point of the question was more about understanding and learning, as opposed to copying and pasting other peoples code and trying to get it to work.

*Starting with the comment by GSerg:*

> C++'s bool is not C#'s bool. UnmanagedType.Bool is C++'s BOOL, not bool.

I was using this list when converting data types:

Table below taken from [Converting C++ Data Types to C#](https://www.displayfusion.com/Discussions/View/converting-c-data-types-to-c/?ID=38db6001-45e5-41a3-ab39-8004450204b3) (I am sure there are more official conversion charts around)

> ```
> C++ Type                       C# Type               Size
> --------                       -------               ----
> BOOL                           bool                  1 byte
> BYTE                           byte                  1 byte
> CHAR                           byte                  1 byte
> DECIMAL                        Decimal               16 bytes
> DOUBLE                         double                8 bytes
> DWORD                          uint, UInt32          4 bytes
> FLOAT                          float, single         4 bytes
> INT, signed int                int, Int32            4 bytes
> INT16, signed short int        short, Int16          2 bytes
> INT32, signed int              int, Int32            4 bytes
> INT64                          long, Int64           8 bytes
> LONG                           int, Int32            4 bytes
> LONG32, signed int             int, Int32            4 bytes
> LONG64                         long, Int64           8 bytes
> LONGLONG                       long, Int64           8 bytes
> SHORT, signed short int        short, Int16          2 bytes
> UCHAR, unsigned char           byte                  1 byte
> UINT, unsigned int             uint, UInt32          4 bytes
> UINT16, WORD                   ushort, UInt16        2 bytes
> UINT32, unsigned int           uint, UInt32          4 bytes
> UINT64                         ulong, UInt64         8 bytes
> ULONG, unsigned long           uint, UInt32          4 bytes
> ULONG32                        uint, UInt32          4 bytes
> ULONG64                        ulong, UInt64         8 bytes
> ULONGLONG                      ulong, UInt64         8 bytes
> WORD                           ushort                2 bytes
> void*, pointers                IntPtr                x86=4 bytes, x64=8 bytes
> ```

As I am just starting to learn a little bit of C++, I made the assumption that (c++) BOOL in the list above was equivalent to (c++) bool, and when not having `[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]` was failing I tried adding that, which was also failing.

Quick note for more information on UnmanagedTypes see [Microsoft: UnmanagedType Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.unmanagedtype?view=netframework-4.8) :

> **UnmanagedType.I1** : A 1-byte signed integer. You can use this member to transform a Boolean value into a 1-byte, C-style bool (true = 1, false = 0).

One further bit I liked was in the accepted solution of https://stackoverflow.com/a/32115697/716296 which is not exactly relevant to this question, as I was not really trying to change the c++ side of things, rather using it as a basic snippet of code to learn how things fit together cross language.

> It's also possible to use a ref argument instead of a return value.
>   This is in fact a common pattern in unmanaged interop:

I have seen this "common pattern" used quite often working with 3rd party tools that wrap unmanaged libraries.  Of course, if I am writing my own unmanaged dll's / libraries, I am going to write them to best fit their purpose and usage, unlike the original question which was just a tool to start learning how.

I hope this answer helps a few people (I am terrible at terminology) but the question was pretty basic, and I not only got the answer but found some good references for expanding now as well.